# How to access isolated scope?

Tags: angularjs

[This is a Plunker of my work so far](http://plnkr.co/edit/CPOSPM8NtPGfc2d0I9wI)

```
<label ng-repeat="option in options">
    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="part.options" checklist-value="option" 
           ng-disabled="part.options.length>=2" > {{option.title}}
</label>
```

I'm trying to figure out how disable all options EXCEPT those that have been checked.

If the limit is say, 2; than if the user selects 2 checkboxes the rest should become disabled, but if they change their mind and **UNCHECK** one of their options all the unchecked options becomes available again.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The checked property on the checkbox should work:

```html
<label ng-repeat="option in options">
   <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="part.options" checklist-value="option" ng-disabled="part.options.length>=2 && !checked" > {{option.title}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do extra check if checkbox is checked `part.options.indexOf(option) === -1`:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fYh1FQVkGr5K55O0PmLY?p=preview

```
<label ng-repeat="option in options">
  <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="part.options" checklist-value="option" ng-disabled="part.options.length>=2 && part.options.indexOf(option) === -1" > {{option.title}}
</label>
```